# Malicious Macro Detected when trying to run Python-Script from Excel-VBA

Tags: python, vba

I want to run a simple PythonScript using the below VBA:

```
Sub RunPythonScrip()

Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.shell")

PythonExePath = """C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"""
PythonScriptPath = """C:\Users\user1\PycharmProjects\webscraping\main.py"""

objShell.Run PythonExePath & PythonScriptPath

End Sub
```

However, when I run this VBA I get the following error message:

[image]

---

What settings do I not change so the Macro is not considered as malicious?

Comment: Seems like the problem is with your virus scanner?  What info do you get from the "more information" link?

Comment: It just forwards me to the general information page about malicious macros from Microsoft. There is no solution provided how to avoid this message.

Comment: Have you tried adding the folder where your macro is running from as a trusted location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments changing the file settings to a **trusted location** solved the problem. 
Details can be found here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-in-microsoft-office-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4